# Laravel 10 with Sanctum - Postman "username" key always NULL

Tags: php, laravel, postman, laravel-sanctum, laravel-10

I'm having a issue when trying to do a POST request with Postman. I have a simple API setup in Laravel using Sanctum. I have a register route and a login route. When I send a request to those routes, if I use "username" as a key with the value, the value passed for username is always NULL and therefore can't register the user because I have it set to require a username, email and password. In Postman I've tried sending with Params, form-data, x-www-form-urlencoded, raw and it always sends username as NULL. If I try the login route with an email and password it works great. But if I try with username and password it never works because username becomes Null.  I do have it set in my app to be able to login with email or username and when registering user enters username, email and password.

In my API register method I have:

```
    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'username' => 'required',
        'email' => 'required|email',
        'password' => 'required',
        'c_password' => 'required|same:password',
    ]);

    if($validator->fails()){
        return $this->sendError('Validation Error.', $validator->errors());
    }

    $input = $request->all();
    $input['password'] = bcrypt($input['password']);
    $user = User::create($input);
    $success['token'] =  $user->createToken('MyAppName')->plainTextToken;
    $success['username'] =  $user->username;

    return $this->sendResponse($success, 'User register successfully.');
```

From that I always get the returned error that username is required since username is always passed as Null. driving me crazy. If I change the key to anything else user_name, _username, whatever, it has no problem sending that value and receiving it in my API route. Any ideas why this is happening?

Screen Shots:

[Screen shot of Postman Console after request sent](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e16AJ.png)

[screenshot of form data values and response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8P6tG.png)

[screenshot of a test I did sending $request->all() back from Laravel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ka8Gc.png)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you attach your postman SC and dumped contents of the request body by dd() .   It may help..

Comment: @NahidHasanLimon honestly not really sure what postman SC is or how to get it :)

Comment: oh sorry my bad . I meant postman  => request body screenshot and  request console screenshot!

Comment: are you posting to the correct route? Not sure why it is returning `404 not found` on those requests that error. Do you have the `POST` route setup?

Comment: yes, I have Route:post setup in api.php for 'register' and 'login'. So the url is /api/register and /api/login. The routes are correct because it hits the correct Method and I'm able to successfully post a login request if I login with the email. not sure why it's saying 404.

Comment: another thing to point out. if I change Postman to send body with x-www-form-urlencoded and use $request->getContent() inside the method instead of $request->all() I do see a username value in the content.

Answer (score 0):

Please validate following lists.

- Remove any middleware if applied.
- Validation request file (Pre-validation may change the value of field.)

Comment: that doesn't make a difference either. The only thing I can conclude is that 'username' is a some kind of restricted key?? I don't know, really doesn't make sense but I changed my key that I'm sending to 'user_name' and then I do the code inside the method to change that to 'username' and everything works great.